# Template function with a parameter of type 'const C s[N]' (fixed size array of elements of type C)

Tags: c++

How to make the following code compile?

```
    template <typename C, size_t N>
    constexpr uint64_t cs_hash(const C s[N])
    {
        return N;
    }

    constexpr char sample[] = "communism";

    constexpr uint64_t h = cs_hash(sample);
```

The compiler error with MSVC 2017 is

```
error C2784: 'uint64_t cs_hash(const C [N])': could not deduce template argument for 'const C [N]' from 'const char [10]'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a `const` reference!

```
template <typename C, size_t N>
constexpr uint64_t cs_hash(const C (&s)[N])
{
    return N;
}
```

---

**Explanation**

When you attempt to create a function parameter of type `T []` or `T [N]`, compiler automatically replaces the type with `T *`.

It means that your function declaration is no different from

```
template <typename C, size_t N>
constexpr uint64_t cs_hash(const C *s)
{
    return N;
}
```

Since the parameter type doesn't depend on `N`, there is no way for `N` to be deduced.

But when you use a 'reference to array' parameter, said rule for array parameters doesn't apply, and nothing stops the deduction from working properly.